# Detect input from another phone?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I am creating an app and would like to add a feature. What I want to do is be able to detect some sort of input code from another phone. For example, if phone A has my app and is talking to someone on phone B, if the person on phone B inputs a predetermined code, the app on phone A will do something.

Phone B ---> input code ---> app on phone A takes action

The app on phone A will be running in the background when it receives the input.

If this is not possible, then I have already found ways to do this with a text message using a BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Unless the two phones are within bluetooth/NFC range of each other, stick with SMS. This sounds sketchy though...

Comment: @A--C How about the internet connection?

Comment: @VladSpreys Woops, forgot the most common form of connectivity :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a DTMF recognizer: http://code.google.com/p/dtmf-decoder/

No idea how ripe the project is.  But it may be a source of inspiration for you :).